# Where does the return value of called fn go when ignored?

Tags: language-agnostic

I just saw a code snippet in [Dive into Python](http://diveintopython.net/scripts_and_streams/index.html) where a function was calling another function (that actually returns something other than `None`) and still the calling function does NOT assign the returned value to a variable.

I got alarmed by it and quickly went to try it:

```
>>> def foo(): return "hello_world!"
... 
>>> def bar(): foo()    
...
```

I realize every function in `python` returns (either `None` or something else)

To my surprise when I tried the same logic in my previously learned languages, they seem to show similar behavior:

`C:`

```
#include<stdio.h>

char* foo(){return "hello_world!";}

int main(void){
  foo();                                                 // works!
  return 0;
}
```

`C++`

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

string foo(){return "hello_world!";}

int main(){
  foo();                                                 // works!
  return 0;
}
```

`Java:`

```
public class Test{

  public static String foo(){return "hello_world!";}

  public static void main(String args[]){
    foo();                                               // works!
    System.exit(0);    
  }  
}
```

All this time I was assuming if a function actually returns something, it SHOULD be set to some variable, otherwise where would the returned value go?!

Comment: Into the void, nevermore to be seen.

Comment: Well, you should indeed store return values somewhere. Unless of course when you don't need it.

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged `language-agnostic`?

Comment: @Seth Absolutely, so I retagged it. (Don't you have the privilege yourself?)

Comment: @Karl yeah, but I didn't want to get retag-happy until I learn the art of the thing (plus I didn't want everyone to get mad and have to undo my retag because I did it wrong).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It disappears.

In case of languages and runtimes in which an object is returned that would need to be garbage collected, the result of calling that function is eligible for collection as soon as the function returns.

In case of languages and runtimes that return an object that is reference counted, or similarly protected, to force an immediate cleanup when the object is no longer needed, that cleanup will occur when the function has returned.

Otherwise, for all intents and purposes, the value is just lost. There's no harm done and should be perfectly safe to do.

Comment: "It's perfectly safe" regarding the leaking the return value. It might not be a good idea to ignore it though, especially in many C functions that return error codes.

Comment: Actually no it doesn't in scripting languages like python, perl, bash, etc

Comment: @James Perl has a magical variable `$_` that holds these sorts of things so they aren't lost forever, but that's just Perl. In Python, you can use `_` from the REPL, but that's specially coded for the REPL and will **not** work in a script, or even between functions written in the REPL - it stores the last result from executing a statement on the REPL. So yes, in the general case, it **does** just disappear.

Comment: @Karl  You are right, I stand corrected.  And I also hate the default variable, as it make for hard to read code, when people take advantage of it like they do in perl

Answer (score 4):

> All this time I was assuming if a function actually returns something, it SHOULD be set to some variable, otherwise where would the returned value go?!

It goes into the bit bucket. wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_bucket

An example:

```
std::set<std::string> set_of_strings;
...
set_of_strings.insert (some_string);
```

Here `std::set::insert()` returns a `std::pair`, an iterator pointing to the element in the set and a bool indicating whether an element was added. In this case that returned `std::pair` is just going to disappear. In many cases you just don't care whether an element with the same value was already present. In such cases there is no reason to check the second return value. In many cases you don't care about the iterator, either. So just let it go away.

Some overly pedantic programmers will type the above like this:

```
std::set<std::string> set_of_strings;
...
(void) set_of_strings.insert (some_string);
```

The `(void)` supposedly tells the compiler to ignore the return result. However, the compiler doesn't need to be told to do that. It will ignore the return result if it is not used. What the `(void)` supposed does do is to tell readers of the code that the return value is intentionally being ignored.

However, you would never do this:

```
(void) x = 42.0;
(void) a = b = c = 42;
```

Both of those assignment statements return a value. (You wouldn't be able to say `a = b = c = 42` if it didn't.) This is just but one of many examples showing that you send data to the bit bucket all the time without knowing it.

My recommendation: Don't use `(void)` to announce that you are intentionally ignoring the return result. The compiler doesn't need it, a reasonable reader of the code doesn't needed, and it just makes the programmer who wrote it look like an arrogant know-it-all who most likely knows a lot less than they think they do.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of C, implementation dependant.  Often the result from a function will be placed in a machine register rather than on the stack.  It is then up to the caller as to whether it is used or not.

Comment: What happens under the hood is implementation-dependent - as with everything. The semantics are well-defined.